# Best Solution be able to update database without updating Application

Tags: android, sqlite, saxparser

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
I am looking for advice on the best solution for my application. This application is basically going to be a database of objects that I would like the user to be able to search. The database is going to be constantly updated by myself, not the user, as new products are released often. I've read over a few options and began implementing this using a flat file database but realized that every update to the database would require an update to the app which is not desired. I read about using SAX Parser which seems like a possibility but wondering if there are any other viable options. Thanks in advance! -Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a centralized database that clients connect to over the internet. That way you can have full control of the db without having to bother clients with constant updates.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking as well, do you have any specific examples/ pros cons of different implementations of centralized databases? Thanks!

Comment: That's a very big question. If you're brand new to this sort of thing I'd recommend checking out Google's App Engine as you can code for it in Java (same as Android) and small apps can be hosted for free.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to as "this sort of thing". New to programming or new to android? I have my bachelors degree in software engineering, but this is my first attempt at a android app.

Comment: New to client-server, web based applications. What you'll need is a web service that can serve up data to your android app but also provide an interface for you to go in and add things to the db. If you've ever done any php, ruby, perl or python then look for frameworks written in those languages. Otherwise stick to a language you're comfortable with (Java, I'm assuming) and use a framework compatible with that.

Comment: I work with PHP now at work more than anything so I'll go with that. Do you have any recommendations? Did a quick google search and found a few. We use the ZEND framework here at work but its kind of a hassle.